# Default view isn't loading

Tags: android-studio

I am beginner in Android studio. I am trying to make a splash screen on android studio. But it's not showing my text and images in layout section. Might be it's a small issue but I'm stuck in it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to resynchronize your Gradle, if it does not work you can also go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.

EDIT:
To build your app you need to define your MainActivity in your manifest like:

```
  <activity android:name="com.example.splashscreen.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If this does not work, you might need to open your build configuration clicking on this:[image]

Then select "Edit configurations" and select "Specified activity" in launch options [image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you have the right view when you build your app ?

Comment: Yes I have both view Blueprint and design view. One more issue i'm facing whenever I am trying  to run app it gives "Error running 'MainActivity': Default activity not found".

Comment: @Irfan I edited my answer to help you to run your app, check your manifest to set your MainActivity as the launching activity. I also encourage to check the official doc [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp)